# Series Expansion of $\frac12 (e^{1/m}+e^{-1/m})$

Tags: sequences-and-series

The book I am reading simply states the result that:

$$ \frac{1}{2} (e^{1/m} + e^{-1/m}) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k)!}(\frac{1}{m})^{2k}$$

and similarly

$$ \frac{1}{2} (e^{1/m} - e^{-1/m}) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k+1)!}(\frac{1}{m})^{2k+1}$$

This is what I have tried:

We know that $$e^{1/m} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}(\frac{1}{m})^n $$
and so 
$$\frac{1}{2} (e^{1/m} + e^{-1/m})=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(1/m)^n+(-1/m)^n}{n!}$$
and if we make the substitution $ n = 2k $, we arrive at:
$$\frac{1}{2} (e^{1/m} + e^{-1/m})=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(1/m)^{2k}+(-1/m)^{2k}}{(2k)!} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k)!}{(\frac{1}{m})^{2k}}$$

But I am unsure that such a substitution is mathematically valid!

Comment: Do you know the hyperbolic functions?

Comment: No I haven't been taught about them yet!

Comment: To claim taking into account only even terms $n=2k$ is not enough. You need also to prove that the odd terms $n=2k+1$ vanish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made a good start, correctly achieving

$$\frac{1}{2} (e^{1/m} + e^{-1/m})=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(1/m)^n+(-1/m)^n}{n!}$$

The next step is to recognise that $(1/m)^n+(-1/m)^n$ behaves differently for odd and even values of $n$.

If $n$ is odd, then $(1/m)^n+(-1/m)^n = (1/m)^n-(1/m)^n = 0$

But if $n$ is even, then $(1/m)^n+(-1/m)^n = (1/m)^n+(1/m)^n = 2(1/m)^n$

The condition that $n$ is even is equivalent to $n=2k$

Thus $$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(1/m)^n+(-1/m)^n}{n!}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2(1/m)^n}{n!}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2(1/m)^{2k}}{(2k)!} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k)!}{\left(\frac{1}{m}\right)^{2k}}$$

Answer (score 2):

An idea:

$$\frac12\left(e^{1/m}+e^{-1/m}\right)=\frac12\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac1{m^k k!}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{m^k k!}\right)=$$

$$=\frac12\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1+(-1)^k}{m^k k!}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{m^{2k} (2k)!}$$

since

$$\frac{1+(-1)^k}{m^k k!}=\begin{cases}0,&k\;\text{is odd}\\{}\\\cfrac2{m^kk!},&k\;\text{ is even}\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thank you! So I just need to show that every odd term for my working is in fact 0, as per your working!